# Can I create a Facebook fan page for Super User?

Tags: discussion, support, status-declined

I have created a **Super User** page on Facebook.  I need information such as when Super User was founded, our mission, etc...check out the page and provide insights and suggestions...etc

I also need a high-resolution image of the Super User logo (the existing is low dpi)...

**Update:** This project **did not** go through due to complications and that it would run into various issues (if not created by Stack Exchange itself), thus [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined).

<sub>**Note:** Leaving this up as documentation to those who attempt something like this in the future.</sub>

Comment: Why is this question down voted?

Comment: Because some people don't like Facebook

Comment: @IvoFlipse lousy reason to down vote something that you don't like imho...

Comment: @BloodPhilia Maybe some just don't like the idea of there being a Facebook page, on Meta, downvotes does indicate agreement or disagreement, and since there is no reputation gain it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Diago I see...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I appreciate your enthusiasm for supporting Super User but, unfortunately, that page looks like it's THE official Super User Facebook page. I sounds like a nice idea, but it is going to run up against our Trademark Policy (see [Guidelines for the Use of the Stack Exchange Trademarks](https://superuser.com/legal/trademark-guidance)).

Perhaps it would work better if you can make a Super User fan page. But it would have to be visually clear that it is a fan page by a member of the community. You wouldn't be able to use the logo and name to brand the page, but you can use flair and smaller logos when you are referring to the site in the context of your content. The best thing to do is read the trademark guidelines.

I don't know that much about Facebook; they have fan pages and they have organization pages. I don't know how these work or how you can make it so one can distinguish between "Community pages" and "Official pages." Maybe someone here can fill in the blanks.

But the goal is to make it clear that you are a well-meaning fan and not trying to pass the site off as being THE Super User page. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: This is where my thoughts would be also.  There can be a lot of confusion around official and non-official pages.

Answer (score 5):

You can find all the required information on the SO blog [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com) under the Super User tag. For a more detailed history on the SO and the engine you look at the pod-casts tag.

You will need to email the team at the address at the bottom of the page for the high res logo.

Furthermore, please state clearly that the page is in no way linked or managed by Super User or Stack Exchange Inc; but maintained by members of the site independently.

Comment: +1 for the information, and I wish I could give another +1 for *Furthermore, please state clearly that the page is in no way linked or managed by Super User or StackOverflow LLC but maintained by members of the site independently*

Comment: You can get the high res logo [here](http://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos) - **but** pay attention to the trademark guidelines posted there. These are copyrighted images.

Answer (score 1):

Created an SVG file for the logo, look below =)

http://www.fruityjuice.nl/files/images/Superuser_Logo_Final.svg
http://www.fruityjuice.nl/files/images/Superuser_Logo_Complete_Final.svg

I don't know if this is legal, please let me know if it is not and I'll remove as soon as possible.

Comment: +1: Nice work! :-)

Comment: As mentioned by Roberts please review the trademark guidelines: http://superuser.com/legal/trademark-guidance

Comment: @Diago I don't use, merely provide. I am in no way violating the trademark guidelines as provided on the aforementioned link.

Comment: @Blood Was just pointing you to a place to check the legality of doing this yourself.

Comment: [Uhm...](http://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos).

Comment: @GeorgeEdison I know, but I mainly did it for the textual part! ;)

Comment: @Blood: That's in the ZIP file on that page too :)